# Laravel/Vue | Elastic Beanstalk - Configuration throws error

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to get a Laravel/Vue app running on Elastic Beanstalk.

I've added the following `.ebextensions/npm.config` file:

```
container_commands:
    01_install_gcc:
      command: 'yum install -y gcc-c++ make'
    02_download_node:
      command: "curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -E"
    03_install_node:
      command: 'yum install -y nodejs'
    04_install_node_modules:
      command: 'npm install --save-dev cross-env'
    05_run_production:
      command: 'npm run production'
```

Unfortunately, it is throwing an error.

Platform: PHP 8.1 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.4.1

Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: Did you try only  commands  instead of  container_commands?

Comment: I would not expect the node 6 repo to really support amazon linux 2 to be honest

Comment: @apokryfos, are you saying I should change `setup_6.x` to something more recent? Yes I'm asking that question :D

Comment: @ErkanÖzkök, The above is a copy/paste from another accepted answer

Comment: You can give it a try. I do know that AWS lambda used Amazon Linux for all versions of node up to 10 before switching to Amazon Linux 2 for nodejs 10+ so I would expect no one to bother to maintain a build of node 6 on amazon linux 1 since it would probably be seen as a use case that no one (or maybe only a few people) would have. Also there's a ton of other reasons why you should switch to a newer node version like e.g. security patches

Comment: @apokryfos, didn't work. But perhaps there is another fundamental issue I'm overlooking

Comment: Might be worth sharing the exact error message you are getting it might have hints as to what is going on